# Permissions of User directory are wrong after manual restore

Tags: permission

I manually restored the files in my User directory running `cp` from the Mac OS X Mountain Lion restore disk. Now I can not access my files anymore, and `ls -l` prints this:

```
drwx------   2 root    admin    68 17 Okt 21:29 Applications
drwx------   5 root    admin   170 17 Okt 21:29 Desktop
drwx------  11 root    admin   374 17 Okt 21:37 Documents
drwx------   3 fabian  admin   102 19 Okt 08:57 Downloads
drwx------  46 root    admin  1564 18 Okt 20:32 Library
drwx------  14 root    admin   476 18 Okt 20:44 Movies
drwx------   5 root    admin   170 18 Okt 20:56 Music
drwx------  17 root    admin   578 18 Okt 22:31 Pictures
drwx------   4 fabian  admin   136 19 Okt 08:57 Public
```

From what I understand, it should say fabian instead of root everywhere, but I can't seem to figure out the right command to change this. So, does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right command for changing the owner is `chown`

```
$ chown owner:[group] file_name
```

you can type the following line for retrieving more information

```
$ man chown
```

You can also try to run Disk Utility, wihch provide a tool for fixing the wrong Disk Permissions.

1. Open Disk Utility
2. Select your HD
3. Click *Verify Disk Permissions*
4. After looking at the result you can run *Repair Disk Permissions*